# slashes are missing while updating filepath using Server.MapPath in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

while updating file path using asp.net slashes are missing in db

can any one help in solving this

thanks in advance

```
 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var temp = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/folder/Images/"), fileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    var newFullPath = path;
    int Imgnamecount = 1;
    while (System.IO.File.Exists(newFullPath))
    {
          string tempFileName = string.Format("{0}({1})", fileNameOnly, Imgnamecount++);

          newFullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/folder/Images/")), tempFileName + extension);
          temp = tempFileName;

    }
    file.SaveAs(newFullPath);
```

Comment: it will save url according to the system what i remeber is sql server replaces slashes with some character in db

Comment: you need to save only relative path in db and while fetching get absolute url using Server.MapPath

Comment: i am using mysql server while inserting the file path it is working fine ...

Comment: i am getting the issue while updating the filepath...

Answer (score 0):

Try using \ instead of /. Sometimes (back)slashes are used as escape character.